# Cross-Origin AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Sometimes the rules make no sense to me.

How do people make an ajax request to a google api or something like that? I mean does everything have to be cross-origin? It seems stupid... why can't I make a nonblocking ajax get request to google..

I've heard you can use jsonp-- but in that case the server has to support that format. I want a way to make async ajax get requests to cross-origin pages.

Comment: As long as its jsonp or json and the sever supports them, you can do calls to the site. So most apis work. If you want instead to get html, you will need to use a server as middleman

Comment: Which google API are you trying to use?  What error do you get?  Please post the code that you're trying to use.

Comment: Dude I'm just speaking in generalities. You can't access any google api cross origin unless you send a special header right?

Comment: And how can you make async get requests cross origin? I mean whats up with these specs? Its annoying--> your webapp will be slow if you don't support jsonp right?

Comment: HELPPPPPP pleaseee